# Now refresh data after add item using RxJs and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I can't refresh angular material table after add new item.
Check my problem. First my structure of component:

Home folder inside
Item 1 folder with ts html scss
Item 2 folder with ts html scss

These two components are INDEPENDENT. No parent child..no sibling.
On click on row of table Item 1 I showing Item 2 table.
I take the id from item 1 table and make a call to item 2 + id from item 1.

For live refreshing I am using RXJS
which works when adding or deleting or updating the table being worked on. For example, if I add something to the table item 1, the data is immediately refreshed. Check code:

Service:

```
private _liveRefreshData$ = new Subject<void>();

  liveAutoRefresh() {
    return this._liveRefreshData$;
  }  

 postItem(item) {
 return this.http.post('api' , item).pipe(
    tap(() => {
      this._liveRefreshData$.next();
    })
  );
```

in component onInit only do:

```
this.apiService.liveAutoRefresh().subscribe(() => {
  this.functionWhichGetDataAndSubscriberOn(); 
});


functionWhichGetDataAndSubscriberOn() { // this is item 2 getter
this.subscription.push(
  this.apiService.getDataIDFromItem1(this.item_1_ID).subscribe( //get item1 id to call item 2
    (data) => { 
      this.documents = data; 
    },
    (error: any) => console.log(error)
  )
);
```

}

Problem?
I need to refresh data but no work. On same component and same item this is work. Example. If I add item 1 in item 1 component table this is work, but when add item 2 from item 1 component ( it is important I need to add item 2 from item 1 component dialog ) I got problem.

simply my list is not refreshed. I add an item and I need to refresh the pages to see the newly added item again or click again to row item to make new api call to and show newly item.

**Question how to solve this? is it possible to do it this way or to look for another one? I just have to refresh live data, add an item, the problem is that I add 2 independent tables from one table to another.**

Comment: Sorry, but the code you provided is not sufficient. Please, explain in more detail how your entire process works. How do you provide the id needed? As far as I understand you put it somewhere and then you trigger the process. Where, for example, derives `item_1_ID` from?

Comment: Is the second component already started? Or is it called only when the user clicks a button?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, your code provided is still lacking some important information. I'll edit your code a little in order to show you how I would solve it.

Let your **Service** hand in the id with the Observable.

```
private _liveRefreshData$ = new Subject<number>();

liveAutoRefresh(): Observable<number> {
    return this._liveRefreshData$.asObservable();
}  

 postItem(item) {
     return this.http.post('api' , item).pipe(
         tap(() => {
             this._liveRefreshData$.next(item.id);
         })
  );
```

And in your component with the second table use the id as follows:

```
this.apiService.liveAutoRefresh().subscribe( id => {
    this.functionWhichGetDataAndSubscriberOn(id); 
});


functionWhichGetDataAndSubscriberOn(id: number): void {
    this.subscription.push(
          this.apiService.getDataIDFromItem1(id).subscribe(
              (data) => { 
                  this.documents = data; 
              },
              (error: any) => console.log(error)
          )
);
```

If the rest of your implementation is correct, this is supposed to work.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the  answer accordingly. Thx in advance.

Comment: If you have a Service as kind of a broadcaster (one component puts data into an Observable via a setter and all subscribers to this Observable get updated via subscription) then it is irrelevant in which relationship they are. This is what services providing Observables are there for. So yes, I am sure indeed. I use this practice between Parent and Child as well as Siblings or actually non related components. The Observable in a service puts aside any need to consider relationships between sender and receiver.

Comment: So if it still does not work I need to see snippets of your HTML-template.